# isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled always YES

Tags: objective-c, ios7

`[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled]` always returns `YES`,
although i have disabled `Ad-Tracking` in the `Settings`.
Already terminated and restarted the App.
Has somebody else seen this behavior too?
I have just started using the `advertisingIdentifier` (as the MAC address is no longer available in iOS7) and so my experiences using the `AdSupport` framework are limited...

Thanks!

UPDATE
I have installed the App several times on a second Device via Ad Hoc Distribution (thus using a Distribution Profile) and there it works. So maybe this is only Development related...

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the device?

Comment: @DavidCaunt Yes, with no luck...

Comment: @DavidCaunt That (reboot) shouldn't be necessary, right? Or is it?

Comment: I've no idea but I was guessing that it might not take affect until the device is rebooted. Sorry I can't help.